# Why would Linux kernel drop the isolcpus parameter?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu, kernel-parameters

I'm trying to pass `isolcpus=1-4` to the kernel command line, Linux version 5.10.42 LTS. My boot manager is `EFISTUB`/`efibootmgr`. I'm booting OK but the parameter is simply not there when checking with

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline 
root=UUID=478aa208-4132-4ca4-bf86-188cb1ecb3f6 rw initrd=\intel-ucode.img initrd=\initramfs-linux-lts.img
```

The parameter is missing.
I have the exact same kernel, software and setup including the kernel configuration (albeit different hardware) on a different machine where the parameter is picked up, and even works! So I'm suspecting something to do with the motherboard/bios? (Asus Pro WS W480). How can I troubleshoot this? `journalctl` lists the commandline stripped:

```
kernel: Linux version 5.10.42-1-lts (linux-lts@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 11.1.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.36.1) #1 SMP Thu, 03 Jun 2021 12:54:28 +0000
kernel: Command line: root=UUID=478aa208-4132-4ca4-bf86-188cb1ecb3f6 rw initrd=\intel-ucode.img initrd=\initramfs-linux-lts.img
```

Whereas the on the machine where it works, the commandline contains the param obviously.

Comment: My idea of `/proc/cmdline` is that it reflects the kernel parameters verbatim. If your parameter is not there, then you should check your grub configuration and grub-install again. Besides, the backslashes are highly suspicious (again check your grub conf).

Comment: Thanks but the questions mentions I'm not using GRUB but plain EFI (`efibootmgr`). Like here - https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFISTUB#efibootmgr . Which works great otherwise without any other dependencies.

Comment: I'm having this problem too on Ubuntu 22.04. I set isolcpus but it doesn't show in the cmdline. Did you discover what happened?

Comment: @mezamorphic after a LOT of trial and error I concluded it is some sort of MB/BIOS bug. The original idea had been to have 2 efibootmgr entries and then I can select either one to boot. But I think the BIOS was somehow interfering with that. AFAIK I deleted all entries except the isolcpus one, and thta's how it worked. So it looked like the BIOS or something else was not respecting the "order" of the boot entries - which as you know you can alter.